# Create dynamic date filename using a stored procedure and a datetime variable

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2005, dynamic, filenames

I realise in most cases this is a trivial problem but it just doesn't seem to be working for me at the minute. I have a stored procedure that creates a Datetime variable then using datepart finction to create a string that is set as a filename. I have borrowed another piece of code which outputs in the format yyyymmdd but I need ddmmyyyy and a simple reshuffle doesn't seem to be working.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
 @Date datetime,
 @FileName varchar(14) OUTPUT

 as


/* Year */
SET @FileName = convert(char(4),datepart(yy, @Date))
/* Months */
IF datepart(mm, @Date) <= 9
SET @FileName = @FileName + '0'+ convert(char(1), datepart(mm, @Date))
ELSE
SET @FileName = @FileName + convert(char(2),datepart(mm, @Date))
/* Day */
IF datepart(dd, @Date) < =9
SET @FileName = @FileName + '0'+ convert(char(1), datepart(dd, @Date))
ELSE
SET @FileName = @FileName + convert(char(2),datepart(dd, @Date))
```

This is the borrowed code and I tried to rearrange it as follows but only the yyyy part appears:

```
/* Day */
IF datepart(dd, @Date) < =9
SET @FileName = @FileName + '0'+ convert(char(1), datepart(dd, @Date))
ELSE
SET @FileName = @FileName + convert(char(2),datepart(dd, @Date))
/* Months */
IF datepart(mm, @Date) <= 9
SET @FileName = @FileName + '0'+ convert(char(1), datepart(mm, @Date))
ELSE
SET @FileName = @FileName + convert(char(2),datepart(mm, @Date))
/* Year */
SET @FileName = convert(char(4),datepart(yyyy, @Date))
```

Upon inspection, I have noticed some issues with my code so I changed the lack of a + in the /* year */ block and I also removed th IF statements however this has not sorted the issue:

```
/* Day */
SET @FileName = convert(char(2),datepart(dd, @Date))

/* Months */
SET @FileName = @FileName + convert(char(2),datepart(mm, @Date))

/* Year */
SET @FileName = @FileName + convert(char(4),datepart(yy, @Date))
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and show us the input and desired output?

Comment: If you are using SQLServer 2012+ you can use `FORMAT`

Comment: The input is simply the #date variable and the output is reformatting different parts of this variable and making it a string for a filename. This is stored in the #FileName variable and is used within another stored procedure to append the date to a filename. The issue here is that it is for an automated process and must be picked up in the format ddmmyyy. @ZoharPeled

Comment: Sorry but I'm using a work laptop and so am limited to SQLSERVER2005, I'm currently an apprentice at an IT company hence my difficulty in what seems to be a simple problem @Serpiton

Comment: In addition I have noticed that within the /* Year */ code block the FileName = convert section there is no '+' so this would overwrite whatever was stored on the varible I have since changed this on the system and in my question, I think the issue may be the IF statements

Comment: @ShaneToner that's why is important to use the relevant tag, if SQLServer can be extracted from the code nowhere is stated that is SQLServer 2005

Comment: apologies this was my first post, I understand it is naive to expect problems to be universal

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work for you?

```
select replace(convert(varchar(10),@Date,103),'/','')
```

Comment: There seems to be an issue with using the SELECT statement within a stored procedure so I'm not sure this would help

Comment: Sorry for "steeling" your answer, I swear I didn't see it when I posted mine... friends? :-)

Comment: I tried both solutions from Narti and Zohar and neither seemed to work when I ran the 'job' containing the stored procedure the file wasn't picked up

Comment: @Serpiton my code is the stored procedure all that is missing is the create procedure etc; then it begins by declaring the variables

Answer (score 0):

SQLServer 2012 or better as the function `FORMAT` that IMO is exactly what you need

```
@Date datetime,
@FileName varchar(14) OUTPUT

SET @FileName = FORMAT(@Date, 'ddMMyyyy')
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19500)</kbd> edited to be standalone

Comment: I'm currently using SQLSERVER2005 and don't have much room for movement as it is in work, is there a relevant alternative?

Comment: @ShaneToner you can use the answer from Narti changing `SELECT` into `SET @FileName = ` like [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19643)

Answer (score 0):

If your input is a datetime and desired output is a string in ddmmyyyy format, try this:

```
@Date datetime,
@FileName varchar(14) OUTPUT

SET @FileName = REPLACE(CONVERT(char(10), @Date, 103),'/', '');
```

[CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function is a built in function in sql server that will return you (in this case) a string formatted as dd/mm/yyyy.

[REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186862%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) function is a built in function that will remove the / chars from that string.

Comment: Have you see the answer that Narti wrote yesterday?

Comment: Just now... sorry Narti... however, since this answer contains also links to the msdn pages of the functions used, I think the OP can benefit a little more from it.